# How to create simple 2d jump

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple 2d scrolling game where a car will jump over obstacles when the space bar is clicked, similar to the Chrome dinosaur game. While I have been able to, more or less, create what I'm looking for in html and css, I have no idea how to get the car to not only jump when space is clicked, but also respond to touching obstacles. I'm sure this is easy to program, but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here my code so far:

```js
// I want to make the 'car,' along with its wheels jump when the space bar is clicked in order to avoid 'obstacles.' If the car/wheels touch the obstacles, I want the game to restart.
// If you could somehow include directions to create some sort of scoreboard, that would be great!
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#bird{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: transformx(-100px);
  animation: bird 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bird{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0) translatex(1000px) translatey(100px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1500px, 0, 0) translatex(1000px) translatey(100px);
  }
}

#sky{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 250px;
  width: 5000px;
  transition: transformx(-100px);
  animation: sslide 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes sslide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0) translatex(-60px) translatey(-30px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0) translatex(-60px) translatey(-30px);
  }
}

#dunes{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 350px;
  width: 2500px; 
  animation: dslide .8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dslide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0) translatex(-50px) translatey(140px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0) translatex(-50px) translatey(140px);
  }
}

#road{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
  width: 2500px;
  animation: rslide .1s linear infinite;
}

.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes rslide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0) translatex(-50px) translatey(257px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-300px, 0, 0) translatex(-50px) translatey(257px);
  }
}

#left{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(19px at 50% 52%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: lwheel .08s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lwheel{
  from {
    transform: translatex(7px) translatey(405px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translatex(7px) translatey(405px) rotate(359deg);
  }
}

#right{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(19px at 50% 52%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
   -webkit-animation: rwheel .08s infinite linear;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes rwheel{
  from {
    transform: translatex(188px) translatey(405px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translatex(188px) translatey(405px) rotate(359deg);
  }
}

#car{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 125px;
  width: 325px;
  transform: translatex(-20px) translatey(370px) rotate(2deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img id='road' src="https://c0.piktochart.com/v2/uploads/ed043d80-66dc-4ec9-a40e-d6e00a7ba006/1f8f1cb08d9268d7d8cbec851fccc2201d7c53d8_original.png"></img>
  <img id='dunes' src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/nodiatis/images/a/a1/Desert_Dunes-Main.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090727220300"></img>
<img id="sky" src="http://www.blueskyamusements.com/images/site/template/bkg-sky.jpg"> </img>
<img id="bird" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flying-bird-transparent-background--5.png"></img>


</div>


<img id='car' src="https://i.ibb.co/jyWMPQN/photo-1514723432099-9f0d4906e6e9-burned.png"></img>
<img id='left' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496989981497-27d69cdad83e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=047c1b03d7f3fdf3ddb8f346901fd759"></img>
<img id='right' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496989981497-27d69cdad83e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=047c1b03d7f3fdf3ddb8f346901fd759"></img>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Well, most of the logic will be performed by JavaScript so it would be nice of you to post the JS code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matus. Thats kind of my problem, I don't know where to start. I don't really have anything right now.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/105955605 - This is a wonderful talk about writing games in javascript - the bits about collision detection would be a worthwhile investigation. Best of luck in your endeavor!

Comment: Thank you Forty!